# facing Issue while MERGE/UPSERT snowflake from a parquet file staged on S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below Script i written for parquet file, but when i am executing it its inserts null values in all the fields.

```
MERGE INTO data_architecture_stage.test ex USING ( 
SELECT $1:device_attr_hk, 
$1:applicationruntime_raw 
FROM @dss_prod.test.subscriber_data_solutions/rollup_parquet_expor2t/ (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet') 
) ne ON ex.device_attr_hk = ne.$1:device_attr_hk 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 

UPDATE SET device_attr_hk = ne.$1:device_attr_hk , applicationruntime_raw = ne.$1:applicationruntime_raw 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (device_attr_hk, applicationruntime_raw) VALUES (ne.$1:device_attr_hk, ne.$1:applicationruntime_raw);
```

**I wants to know, what am I doing wrong here.**